# Shortening template function call with enum class as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, enums

NB: This if purely for self-education.

I have following template:

```
template <typename T, T val>
void Foo() {
    static_assert(false, "You should not be here");
}
```

and I want to create many specializations, like this:

```
enum class ENUM { A, B };

template<>
void Foo<ENUM, ENUM::A>() {
    // something
}
```

This code works correctly with ENUM::A as template argument, and correctly triggering static_assert, when called not with ENUM::A.

The question is - call syntax for such functions is very ugly, like this:

```
Foo<ENUM, ENUM::A>();
```

Is there any way to shorten it for just

```
Foo<ENUM::A>();
```

But, leaving intact the idea, that other enum-types can be passed as template parameter.

Code below is *NOT* a solution

```
template <ENUM val>
void Foo() {} // and further specialize only for values of ENUM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't think of a way to do it exactly as you want.

However, if you're willing to invest some effort (in a way which can be mitigated, moreover - below) in order to make the various versions easy to call, you could use [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) to make things into types;

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                             
#include <type_traits>


using namespace std;


enum class ENUM{ A, B };
using AT = integral_constant<ENUM, ENUM::A>;
using BT = integral_constant<ENUM, ENUM::B>;


template<typename T>
void Foo();


template<>
void Foo<AT>()
{
    cout << "a" << endl;
}


int main ()
{
    Foo<AT>();

    return 0;
}
```

Why is this better than before?

1. You might think it's not!
2. If you're planning on writing a lot of code *calling* these functions, it might be a saving.
3. It's quite easy to write a macro to automate those `using`s at the top.